# The Force exerted by a Pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

So I was messing around with a pendulum, and was wondering how the force exerted by the pendulum change at different points of its trajectory. So, I came up with the following set up:[image: Setup]

What I did to find out the effect of the position on the force exerted on the sensor was that I moved the force sensor back and adjusted the clamp such that the new position of the sensor would match with the point in the trajectory of the pendulum I wanted to investigate. After graphing the results, I observed the obvious decreasing trend in force exerted as position along the trajectory (starting from the mean position) increased. 
Given that this would be an inelastic collision, could an equation be formulated for this scenario, which would calculate the force exerted by the pendulum on the sensor given the height from the mean position? 
Thank you!

Comment: You need to tell a bit more about how you actually measure the force. Do I understand correctly that in your experiment you have the pendulumn swing back and forth and at some point you let it collide into your force sensor which measures only the horizontal component of the "force"? How exactly does this force sensor look like, particularly how does it give you a number from the collision?

Comment: The force will vary with time. The integral of force over time gives the impulse, which equals the change in momentum of the pendulum mass. The duration of the impulse depends on the elasticity of the colliding objects, and affects the peak force recorded. The collision is not necessarily elastic.

Comment: So what I do is I pull the pendulum to a 30 degree angle and let it go, and it collides with the force sensor in the first swing itself. I adjust the force sensor for multiple positions such as the mean position and a few following the trajectory. So, for these different points in the trajectory I would like to know a formula for the force exerted. The force sensor measures push and pull forces, so only the compression it faces when the pendulum hits it.

Comment: Time is not of importance here as the pendulum collides with the force sensor before completing a full oscillation.

Answer (score 0):

For small amplitudes (small "initial height from mean") the solution for the angle as a function of time $t$ is:

$$\theta(t) = \theta_0\cos\omega t,$$

where $\omega=\sqrt{g/l}$ is the oscillation frequency, $l$  the length of the pendulum, $g$ the gravitational acceleration and $l(1-\cos\theta_0)$ is the "initial height from mean".

Written in cartesian coordinates the position of the pendulum bob is:

$$\mathbf{r}=\begin{bmatrix}
l\sin\theta\\
l\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}$$

[image]

From this you can calculate the velocity $d\mathbf{r}/dt$ of the bob.

If your "force sensor" is only sensitive to the horizontal component, only the x-component of the velocity ($v_x$) will be relevant.

This x-component will be relevant for the collision and detector reading, either through the momentum, $mv_x$ or kinetic energy $mv_x^2/2$.

It is impossible to say much more not knowing any details about the detector.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say anything with certainty about the *force* exerted. However, you can say something about the *momentum* of the bob - which is completely absorbed during the inelastic collision.

We note first that the change in momentum $\Delta(mv) = \int F\cdot dt$. If mass is constant, and force is constant, then $m\Delta v = F\Delta t$, so the problem of finding force becomes a problem of finding the time taken to slow the bob down.

We note next that if the pendulum of length $
\ell$ is released at an angle $\theta$ from the vertical, it will start at a height $h$ above the equilibrium position:

$$h = \ell \left(1-\cos\theta\right)$$

If the impact with the sensor is made while the bob is at an angle $\phi$ to the vertical (where of course $\phi \lt \theta$, otherwise it would not be able to hit), we can again compute the height with an analogous equation. The velocity $v$ of the bob at the time of impact is computed from the kinetic energy, which follows from the difference in height (difference in potential energy between initial and final position):

$$\frac12 mv^2 = mg (h_i-h_f)=mg\ell\left(\cos\phi-\cos\theta\right)\\
v_{impact} = \sqrt{2g\ell\left(\cos\phi-\cos\theta\right)}$$

Now the momentum is absorbed by exerting a force $F$ during a time $\Delta t$; without a lot more detail about the compliance of the force sensor, we can't predict whether the bob will stop in 0.1 ms or 10 ms - and the difference will be a factor 100 in force (for the same value of momentum).

We could, however, assume that this compliance has some relationship to the momentum. This leads to different results depending on the assumption.

If we assume that the force exerted is proportional to the velocity of impact (this is the case for viscous damping at the low Reynolds number limit), then the time taken to slow down will be independent of the initial velocity, and the average force during the impact will be directly proportional to the velocity.

If we assume that the recorded force is the result of a perfectly elastic collision (with a spring constant $k$), then the maximum force measured will be reached when the spring has absorbed all the kinetic energy; for a velocity $v$ this happens when $\frac12 m v^2 = \frac12 k x^2$, so $x\propto v$ and since $F=kx$ we once again find that the (peak) force recorded is proportional to the velocity.

Other mechanisms for the force sensor may result in different relationships.